# How does a facade getFacadeAccessor() method work?

Tags: laravel

I am reading through the Laravel documentation to try and achieve a deeper understanding of the framework but I am having a bit of trouble with facades. I think I understand what they are, they are mostly used for convenience when accessing Laravels core.

My confusion is with this topic:

> 1. How does a facade work? (Specifically related to the getFacadeAccessor() method. Is this magic?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facades is another way to use classes without manually creating an object. They are just a shortcut to classes registered by [Laravel container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container).

For example, this:

```
DB::
```

Makes absolutely the same as if you'd use the container:

```
app('db')->
```

So, `DB::` facade is just a shortcut for `app('db')->`.

And yes, facades use the magic method [`__callStatic()`](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Facades/Facade.php#L213) which resolves an instance of a class and executes given method:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }

    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```